# Incorrect number of bindings supplied python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm executing the following query in sqllite

```
idP = cur.execute('SELECT id from profs where name = ?',name)
```

I have a database table like this:

```
| id |   name   |
| 1  |  xxxxxx  |
```

but I got an error : Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied.

I think that the string 'xxxxxx' is seen as six individual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert the parameter to a tuple:

```
idP = cur.execute('SELECT id from profs where name = ?',(name,))
```

Comment: thanks, i think it works, but why do we have to write a comma after name

Comment: I think its just the python way because it says "A tuple consists of a number of values separated by commas" plz accept as answered if your'e done and want to close this question.

Comment: and i have another question , if we know exactly the query will return only one row, is there some way to get that row (not the address) ? otherwise we can only use iterator for get it ?

Comment: What do you mean by address?

Comment: if i print(idP), <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1011dcc00> will get . but i wanna the id .

Comment: I think that will have something to do with the cursorclass of the MySQLdb, cause I guess the default cursor will get all the data but Im not that sure bout it.

Answer (score 0):

The execute method expects an iterable (list, tuple etc.) of length 1 in this case as the bindings argument. So it tries to iterate over the string when you pass it in. You should put the string in a list and pass that in instead:

```
idP = cur.execute('SELECT id from profs where name = ?',[name])
```

Comment: so [name] is the same as (name,)? i think both works.